# C++11 threads: notify_all() or notify_one() when I only have one?

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

My threads operate as a linked list(with overlap, hence threads), implementing something not dissimilar to a timeline. Each condition variable unlocks the next thread in the linked list.

Should I use `notify_all()` or `notify_one()` when I have only one to notify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `notify_one` unless your code makes it easier to read `notify_all` (for example you've constructed a list which just happens to have one element in it).

Comment: Some how I feel this answer needs more justification.